# Impala: create parquet from mysql dump

Tags: impala, parquet

I have mysql dumps, how can I convert them in parquet file format with Impala?

I know that I can create parquet files from CSV but I would like to create parquet files directly without this double step.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use a two step process but I'm **sure** there are better ways.  We use this way to keep the parquet table online so there is as much uninterruptible service during the update as possible.

```
sqoop import --table <mysql_table> --hive-import --hive-table <hive_text_table>

impala-shell -i <impala_ip_addr> -q 'use <db>; INVALIDATE METADATA <hive_text_table>; CREATE TABLE <parquet_table> LIKE <hive_text_table> STORED AS PARQUET; INSERT OVERWRITE <parquet_table> SELECT * FROM <hive_text_table>;'
```

A little long winded but just in case you don't get any other answers.